# Green function of solutions of inhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: solution-verification, wave-equation, greens-function

If $G(\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t)$ is the Green function of wave equation, then solutions for inhomogeneous wave equation will be

$\left( -\Delta + \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right) u(\vec{x}, t) = f(\vec{x}, t)$

can be formed as

$$u(\vec{x}, t) = \int d\xi d\tau G_I (\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t-\tau)f(\vec{\xi}, \tau)$$

where functions $G_I$ are ($\eta$ is Heaviside's function):

$G_R(\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t-\tau) = G(\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t-\tau)\eta(t-\tau)$
$G_A(\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t-\tau) = -G(\vec{x}, \vec{\xi}, t-\tau)\eta(\tau-t)$

Why are there two Green's functions? Are they the only Green's functions?
What conditions do they meet?

Where is the "-" sign from?

What initial conditions does solution for each of the functions meet?

What is their difference?

Appreciate it!